# android volley JsonObjectRequest which returns no body just 200

Tags: android, json, android-volley

How to make a JSON request in volley where I need to send an authentification header and JSON object in body and I expect only an status code 200 answer

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                method,
                url,
                myJsonObject,
                responseListener,
                errorListener) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String creds = String.format("%s:%s", login, password);
                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };


new Response.Listener<String>(){

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, 1000).show();

                                }
```

I tried different kinds of response listeners with string or JSON object, object, but always there is an error:
android volley org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Or is there any other kind of request in volley which supports and json object and authentification header in body and response is just a http status code ?

Answer (score 7):

I know its an old question but i thought i still answer this as my answer might help people in future -

You need to create a custom class that extends Request class and in that class override these methods

```
    @Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        return Response.success(response.statusCode, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(Integer statusCode) {
        mListener.onResponse(statusCode);
    }
```

This is the heart and soul of the class.

For full code and explanation check out my blog on the topic -

Getting a server response status 200 from Android Volley library

[link 1](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/getting-a-server-response-status-200-from-android-volley-library/)

Hope it helps,
Thanks

Comment: answering old questions ftw!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Varundroid and Itai Hanski. It's correct, you just need to subclass the JsonObjectRequest.

For convenience here's my override:

```
public class MyJsonObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest { 
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            // here's the new code, if jsonString.length() == 0 don't parse
            if (jsonString.length() == 0) {
                return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
            // end of patch
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

So I just use that instead of `JsonObjectRequest`. 
Not too pretty, not too ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The `JsonObjectRequest` is used when you expect the network response to be a JSON object. Since you're not expecting that, you shouldn't be using it.

Volley comes with a few predefined popular types of requests for ease of use, but you can always create your own. I suggest making a custom request based on `JsonObjectRequest`, but with a different implementation of the `parseNetworkResponse()` method that does not expect the response to be a JSON object, since you aren't receiving one. You can add any other changes you need there.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create custom class which extends Request as @varundroid stated. 
You can just override `parseNetworkResponse` method instead of `onResponse` method and return success response with empty JSONObject().

Following is the code I'm using to overcome the same problem you are facing. I hope this helps you too

```
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
if (response != null && response.data.length == 0)
    return Response.success(new JSONObject(), null);
else
    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}
```